# Can't understand weird notation $\mu_h = \sum_{X_{i_h} = X^p_L} \lambda_p - \sum_{X_{i_h} = X^q_U}\lambda_q$

Tags: notation

I'm trying to implement alghorithm from article, but stucked since i can't understand weird notation.

"Let $\mathcal{I} = \{i_1, ..., i_M\}$ be the index set of those patterns $X_{i_h}$ that appear as either $X_L$ or $X_U$ in $V$. We have then 
$$V = \sum_{j = 1}^K\lambda_{T-j}(y^{T-j}_LX^{T-j}_L - y^{T-j}_UX^{t-j}_U) = \sum_{h = 1}^M\mu_hy_{i_h}X_{i_h},$$
where for $T-K \le p, q \le T- 1 $ we use notation 
$$\mu_h = \sum_{X_{i_h} = X^p_L} \lambda_p - \sum_{X_{i_h} = X^q_U}\lambda_q."$$
How can i interpret that?

I'm asking because after all of this they are recounting coefficients using this weird notation: $ \alpha_j^{T+1} = \alpha_j^T$ if $j \notin\mathcal{I}, \alpha^{T+1}_{i_h} = \alpha^T_{i_h} + \lambda_T\mu_{i_h}$. And this coefficients i need to recount in my program, but i can't figure out how.

Comment: Which article are you referring to?

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: @Shaun i'm reffering to https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221165881_An_accelerated_MDM_algorithm_for_SVM_training

Comment: What's the first thing about the notation that you don't understand?

Comment: @Shaun 1. why it has double sum?(after substitution in V expression) 2. What will actually my $\alpha$'s be for  $X^p_L, X^q_U$?